# mailchimp Connecting to url failed

Tags: rss, mailchimp, feed

For email campaign based on rss feed, it shows error on clicking next.
My feed is ok but mailchimp doesn't accept that and shows this:

> Connecting to url (http://mywebsite.xyz/blog/feedrss) failed.

[this is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUUkf.jpg)

Reason:
Unfortunately, it was due to sanctions, but nothing was mentioned in the error message.

Comment: How did you find out that your Mailchimp's account had sanctions?

Answer (score 1):

After removing the AAAA / IPV6 records for our domain from our registrar, Mailchimp started accepting the feed. I am using name.com

I was noticing that pinging the domain was timing out sometimes, which shouldn't happen. It should have reverted to IPV4, but didn't.